# REST API get resource and create if not exists on server

Tags: rest

Similar questions have been asked, but I haven't found this exact flavor.

I have a REST API for a "widget".  The widget ID is well known by the client.  I need to GET a widget - for example

```
GET widget/bob
```

But it may not exist. And if it does not, I want the server to create it, and return it.  A "TEMPLATE" widget exists that can be used to create the object and I would like to have this logic on the server.

I know a GET should not have the side effect of creating a resource.

Solutions I've come up with:

- `GET widget/template` and POST this data to `widget/bob` with Header `If-none-match:*` so no operation is performed if widget/bob exists. That's putting the logic on the client and I don't think is a standard header for post
- Same as above, but with a `PUT`
- Custom `POST` endpoint `widget/initialize` (if not exists) that returns the existing or newly created object - but doesn't seem like a standard REST pattern.

What is a solution that solves this in a standard REST way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know a GET should not have the side effect of creating a resource.

That's not quite right; see [Fielding 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html):

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe....

The fact that interesting things are happening behind the API is an implementation detail; the request itself is still [essentially read only](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-safe-methods) - it asked for the current representation of the resource, and you produced one.

Comment: Note: This answer assumes that we're talking about a GET request with no content/request-body.

Comment: Interesting. That would certainly be the easiest solution. And it's not impacting other resources. That's a pretty old spec though.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about age -- maintaining backwards compatibility has been a high priority for the HTTP working group for... 30 years, give or take?